# Can Tzaraas be Declared Nowadays?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, tzaraas-negaim

Based on my understanding of Tzaraas, it seems like what ultimately makes or breaks whether a person is considered impure is whether or not the Kohen declares the person impure.

What would happen nowadays if a Kohen would declare that a person is afflicted with Tzaraas?

Comment: Is he a real Kohein?

Comment: @DoubleAA For the sake of simplicity, we'll say yes, he's a Kohen Meyuchas.

Comment: That's possibly not the only way. According to Yaavetz an obvious tzaaras does not need the cohen declaration. But some argue on him.

Comment: And does he know what the correct shades of white are?

Comment: IIRC, @DoubleAA the consensus among chazal is that tzaraas is no longer "used" in our generations. This would imply that even IF a person were properly trained and normally appropriate to declare someone as a tzaru'a, such declaration must be considered flawed. Much like someone claiming true nevu'a prophecy in our times would likely be considered fraudulent because Chazal say it no longer exists.

Comment: @isa "IIRC" I don't think you remember correctly. Tzaarat is still entirely operative.

Comment: @DoubleAA Wouldn't be the first time, and I'm sure it won't be the last... :)

Comment: @Salmononius2 Where do you find a kohen Meyuchas? I don't think anyone has witnesses who can trace them back to Bayis Sheni

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=14768465#14768465

Comment: @ShmuelBrin That may not be relevant deoraita.